# Python 3.5 fails to apply timezone to parsed iso8601 and always applies system timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to parse an ISO date string in Python, but so far, I'm unable to make Python to apply the parsed timezone; it seems to apply the system on each and every time, unrelated to the parser library I'm trying to use.

What am I missing here?

**machine #1**

```
$ date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
2016-12-12 09:33:23 CET
```

Linux Mint 18, python 3.5 from system package, virtualenv, set to CET as system time:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> t="2015-07-28T17:27:56+0000"

>>> import iso8601
>>> d = iso8601.parse_date( t )
>>> print(d)
2015-07-28 17:27:56+00:00

>>> print(d.strftime('%s'))
1438100876

>>> import pytz
>>> print(d.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%s'))
1438100876

>>> tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')

>>> print( tz.localize( d ) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cadeyrn/petermolnar.net/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 227, in localize
    raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

>>> print(d.astimezone(tz).strftime('%s'))
1438100876

>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> d = dateutil.parser.parse( t )
>>> print( d )
2015-07-28 17:27:56+00:00

>>> print(d.strftime('%s'))
1438100876

>>> print(d.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%s'))
1438100876
```

**machine #2:**

```
$ date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
2016-12-12 08:33:46 UTC
```

Debian 8 Jessie, python 3.5 compiled, virtualenv, set to UTC as system time:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec  9 2016, 16:14:46) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> t="2015-07-28T17:27:56+0000"

>>> import iso8601
>>> d = iso8601.parse_date( t )
>>> print(d)
2015-07-28 17:27:56+00:00

>>> print(d.strftime('%s'))
1438104476

>>> import pytz
>>> print(d.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%s'))
1438104476

>>> tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')

>>> print( tz.localize( d ) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/petermolnar.net/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 227, in localize
    raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

>>> print(d.astimezone(tz).strftime('%s'))
1438104476

>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> d = dateutil.parser.parse( t )

>>> print( d )
2015-07-28 17:27:56+00:00

>>> print(d.strftime('%s'))
1438104476

>>> print(d.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%s'))
1438104476
```

The correct one should be `1438104476` for both, and that's not what happens.